# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "dongle" al español?

Tags: traducción, informática

Tengo un software que está protegido contra la piratería por medio de un *dongle*. Es un molesto aparatito parecido a una memoria USB que hay que mantener conectada al computador mientras se usa el programa.

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle) (la única fuente en que busqué) no aparece traducido:

> Un **dongle** es una pequeña pieza, un hardware, que se conecta a otro dispositivo para aportar una función adicional. En relación con la informática, el término se asocia al mecanismo de copias de seguridad para protección, así como software comercial con el que el dongle se vincula al sistema mediante un software instalado previamente, entregado junto al hardware en la compra.

¿Hay alguna traducción aceptada en español, o alguien sugiere una?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buscando en la web de [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu) veo que hay dos traducciones propuestas para *dongle* en el campo de la informática y el tratamiento de datos:

- Dispositivo de protección.
- Mochila.

La primera opción está marcada como "fiabilidad no acreditada", mientras que la segunda lo está como "fiable". La verdad es que el término "mochila" sí me suena de haberlo usado o haberlo oído usar en el sentido de "dispositivo que permite el uso de software comercial instalado previamente y entregado junto al hardware en la compra".

De hecho, tienes [la siguiente entrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mochila_(dispositivo)) en la Wikipedia:

> En informática, una **mochila**, **llave**, **candado** o **seguro electrónico** (***dongle*** en inglés) es un pequeño dispositivo de hardware que se puede integrar a un programa y se conecta a un ordenador, normalmente, para autenticar un fragmento de software. Cuando la llave electrónica no está conectada, dicho software se ejecuta en un modo restringido o directamente no se ejecuta. Las llaves electrónicas son usadas por algunos fabricantes de software como forma de prevención de copias o gestión de derechos digitales pues es mucho más difícil copiar estas que el software que está instalado. Generalmente las llaves electrónicas se conectan por USB o puerto paralelo.

Comment: Donde trabajo usamos _dongles_, y les llamamos dongles (español rioplatense). Nunca había escuchado "mochila" (¿de dónde viene?). Antiguamente escuché _hardlock_, pero ya no se usa.

Answer (score 0):

Las primitivas mochilas iban conectadas por puertos RS232.

Tengo registrado también el uso de *dongle* para los dispositivos hardware portátiles que se conectan a un ordenador para ampliar las funciones del equipo, tanto de memoria de almacenamiento externo como de conexión a internet u otros dispositivos. (No me pidáis la referencia porque no la tengo)